# Jump to Current Month from Any Month in Calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, nsdate

I am using [SACalendar](https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar). I am trying to achieve jump to Today's date from any month. After Scrolling to any month I should able to move directly to Today's date.

Comment: Just by purely staring at code in Github for 20mins, `[yourCalender.scrollView setPage:0 animated:true]` might give what you want (`reloadData` might also be needed). I could add more explanation in a proper answer if it works for you. (Forgive me if the Obj-C syntax is slight wrong.)

Comment: this is not working at all, i have tried.

Comment: Perhaps you should say what you have tried in the question, and what's wrong with it

Comment: @Sandy why would you use a calendar that was las updated 2 years ago? Here's a list of the top most current calendars dude -> https://cocoapods.org/?q=Calenda

Comment: thanks for sharing, I have done some work around and done as of now. I will using this for future. Thanks.